# Passing Date in an API

Tags: datetime, postman, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on .Net Core and want to post attributes in the api containing dates but I m not able to handle dates for an API. How to overcome with this error.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Server.Dtos
{
    public class ProjectSessionDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Activity { get; set; }
        public string ResourcePerson { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TentativeDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
        public int SemesterId { get; set; }
        public string Program { get; set; }
        public string Batch { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Code...

```html
[HttpPost("addprojectsession")]   //Since there would be 2 Post Methods. Login and Register  
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddProjectSession(ProjectSessionDto projectsession)
  {
    var semester = await _semester.GetSemesterWithProjectSession(projectsession.SemesterId);

    semester.projectsessions.Add(_mapper.Map<ProjectSessionDto,ProjectSession>(projectsession));
    await _semester.AddSemesterWithProject(semester);        
   return Ok();
  }
  
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Aside:  Since this is an API, I highly suggest you have your dates passed in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.  Locale specific formats should not be used in APIs.  For example, one could easily confuse a date like `1/2/2020` between Jan 2nd and Feb 1st depending on which locale they were in.  Passing it as `2020-02-01` makes it clear that it is Feb 1st.  See also https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues you need to fix :

1. In Postman ,change the values with double quotes:

   ```
   "tentativeDate": "12/12/2019",
   "SubmissionDate":"12/12/2019"
   ```
2. In controller , use `[FromBody]`to make asp.net core model binding wokring for reading value from request body :

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> AddProjectSession([FromBody]ProjectSessionDto projectsession)
   ```